# Handling schema refactoring using schema compare tools

Tags: compare, schema, sql-server-data-tools

Let us assume that I want to normalize a table into 2 tables. Eg. A table Person with columns PhoneNumber1...PhoneNumber5 into tables Person and PhoneNumbers with foreign key constraint from Person into PhoneNumber and deletion of PhoneNumber1..PhoneNumber5 columns from the Person table.  I want to preserve data ie PhoneNumber1..PhoneNumber5 should end up as one record each for non-null data in the PhoneNumber table . Can any schema comparison tool help achieve this ?  I checked SSDT and it does not support it even though this "feature" is on their "roadmap"

This is just one simple scenario that I face in my day to day life and we have been using hand-coded SQL to manage this. In a more complicated scenario, one set of tables could change into another set of tables. Is there an easy way in any tool  to manage these kind of schema changes and at the same time manage the data mappings successfully ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes far beyond refactoring in any tool of which I'm aware. SSDT helps you manage and control your schema, but you'll need to handle changes like this through careful planning and handling to avoid data loss.

If you were creating a brand new database to house the new structure/data, that might be different. However as you're trying to do this by renaming/redesigning existing tables, you'll need to be very detailed in your plan and handle it carefully.

You *could* do this through SSDT, but I'd use multiple versions of the product to do it:
1. Create new table with the new structure.
2. Copy data from original to new - requires a custom script.
3. Refactor original table to something like "Name_Backup"
4. Refactor new table to the desired name.

You could likely do steps 1 & 2 in one project and possibly steps 3 & 4 in another version of the project. However you go about it, this sort of refactoring requires more planning and manual work than the more straightforward refactoring of just renaming a column or adding/removing objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I was hoping that a tool existed which would let me 1) deselect tables that I did not want automatically sync'ed and 2) code in custom SQL statements against these tables to sync them to the new set of tables. The tool would then take care of running the custom SQL statements as also it's own auto-generated statements for the rest of the tables in the DB.  This way I do not have to be aware of how the tool worked internally and also did not suffer any performance issues  which I would if I had to do careful planning and execute the changes as a series of steps

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that will take care of all of those behind the scenes and also do it in a way that doesn't cause performance issues. This is a big part of the cost of refactoring your database design. You need to know where the data is going and make sure it gets there. I don't know that I'd actually trust a tool to do that for me as the cost of getting it wrong could be that the data is lost completely. I'm pretty sure you'll need to work these situations manually and try to prevent them as much as possible in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The approach suggested by Peter sounds sensible, e.g.

1. Create PhoneNumbers table
2. Copy data into PhoneNumbers table from People table
3. Modify People table to remove the PhoneNumber1-5 columns

Providing that the time required to copy the data is acceptable within your downtime that could be run as one 'migration'.

If you have a vast amount of data to copy and need to avoid downtime then you could add an abstraction layer to read from both locations while you copy the data over little by little.  Something like:

1. Create PhoneNumbers table
2. Deploy code to read from either People or PhoneNumbers, and write to new PhoneNumbers table only
3. Copy data from People to PhoneNumbers in batches over a period of time
4. Remove code that reads from old People location
5. Modify People table to remove the PhoneNumber1-5 columns

You'd deploy changes 1 & 2, run step 3 for however long it takes or in quiet periods, then deploy changes 4 & 5.

I've found this book [Refactoring Databases: Evolutionary Database Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321293533) by Scott Ambler and Pramodkumar Sadalage really helpful when planning changes like this.

In terms of tooling if you are using SQL Server (or Oracle) you might be interested in taking a look at [Red Gate SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/).  That could handle this change in a single deployment.  Full disclosure - I do work for Red Gate.

SQL Source Control automatically detects changes made in a development database, and links these changes into your existing source control system.  It can then generate the SQL required to synchronise these changes to another database.  There is an advanced feature called Migrations, which allows you to convert a subset of the automatically generated changes into manual SQL steps for more complicated scenarios like this data migration.  You could use Migrations to perform the change described at the top of this post.

In your development database SQL Source Control would have automatically detected the creation of a new PhoneNumbers table, and the deletion of the PhoneNumber1-5 in the People table.  You could select those two changes in the tool and add extra SQL to copy the data over in between them.  It would save that as a Migration script, which [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) would recognise and run when deploying to another database (e.g. a QA/production database), alongside any other changes it finds automatically.